# Redux Form is not initialised with initial values

Tags: javascript, redux-form

I have an application using React Router with an **edit attribute page** containing `<AttributeForm>`. The form on this page is properly displaying `initialValues` passed to it.

On top of the page there's **Clone button** which basically redirects user to **create attribute page**. This page also contains `<AttributeForm>` and I want to prefill form values based on atribute user wants to clone. The problem is that `initialValues` are not displayed here in the form. I think it has to do something with direct transition from page containing the form to another page containing the same form, but idk. I can see the `initialValues` correctly via `console.log(this.props.initialValues)` but they are not displayed.

I also enabled reinitialize, didn't help.

```
const selector = formValueSelector("AttributeForm")
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  sourcesArray: getDataSourcesArrayForSelect(state, true),
  dataType: selector(state, "data_type")
})

AttributeForm = connect(mapStateToProps)(AttributeForm)

export default reduxForm({
  form: "AttributeForm",
  touchOnBlur: false,
  enableReinitialize: true
})(AttributeForm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting `destroyOnUnmount: false`. It was destroying state during page change right after new `initialValues` was set, hence the form was completely clear.